# How can I remove the Finder icon from my Dock?

Tags: macos, finder, dock, customization

I've started using Forklift as a Finder replacement, so I don't need Finder in my Dock. In fact, I would much rather have Forklift be the farthest left icon so I don't accidentally click on Finder.

The usual method of dragging the app out of the Dock doesn't work, and neither does command-dragging. The contextual menu doesn't allow you to remove the icon.

**Is there some way to, on Lion, remove the Finder from the Dock?**
Perhaps there's a database or plist file I can change?

Comment: cDock has this capability.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this, but there is a little hack :)

1. Navigate to /System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/Resources/
2. Backup DockMenus.plist
3. Open DockMenus.plist in your favorite text editor with root access
4. Find section `finder-running` and add new sub-section

   ```
   <dict>
       <key>command</key>
       <integer>1004</integer>
       <key>name</key>
       <string>REMOVE_FROM_DOCK</string>
   </dict>
   ```

   or just [Download](http://cl.ly/05350U3H3V1535170r2A) my version of DockMenus.plist
5. In plist editor file should look like this:

   [image: Plist Editor]
6. Open Terminal and run `killall Dock`.
7. Right click on Finder icon in Dock - Bingo!

   [image: Finder "Remove from dock"]

p.s After Dock restart (manual relaunch or mac reboot) you need manually remove Finder icon from Dock

Comment: Oneliner :) `f=/System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/Resources/DockMenus; sudo cp $f.plist $f-old.plist; sudo defaults write $f finder-running -array-add '<dict><key>command</key><integer>1004</integer><key>name</key><string>REMOVE_FROM_DOCK</string></dict>'; sudo chmod 644 $f.plist; osascript -e 'quit app "Dock"'`. I didn't find any way (other than GUI scripting) to automatically remove Finder from Dock after relogins though.

Comment: Oh and modifying stuff inside Dock's bundle will obviously break its code signature. You might want to back up Dock.app as well.

Comment: @Lri oneliner is efficient but always confusing. About code signature - in case of problems with modified Dock.app you could restore *.plist from backup and run codesign -v /System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/MacOS/Dock.This should solve the problem.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I set up a script to run at login to click the menu item: `tell application "System Events" to tell UI element "Finder" of list 1 of process "Dock"
 perform action "AXShowMenu"
 click menu item "Remove from Dock" of menu 1
end tell`

Comment: Will this break the code signing of the Dock, per Stevetech's answer?

Comment: Nice, but I failed to find REMOVE_FROM_DOCK in 10.8.4 , is there another method I can choose to hide finder please?

Comment: Works for me on Mavericks.  Except that the white 'light' underneath the icon (or rather, where the icon would be) is still there).

Comment: @eebbesen you'd have to quit finder before removing it from Dock.

Comment: Looks like It doesn't work in El Capitan.

Comment: This thread suggests it has something to do with the new "rootless" feature, which might have a workaround http://support.cocoatech.com/discussions/problems/34969-remove-from-dock-option-for-finder-and-trash-broken

Comment: Would be an easy solution, but no "Item 9" appears in the plist editor of Mojave

Comment: This is working great in Mojave for me.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me on HighSierra (10.13.6) with SIP disabled.

I have used the following command to edit the .plist file:

```
PL="/System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/Resources/DockMenus.plist"&&
sudo -- defaults write $PL finder-running -array-add  '<dict><key>command</key><integer>1004</integer><key>name</key><string>REMOVE_FROM_DOCK</string></dict>'
```

Check result with `sudo defaults read $PL finder-running`.

If it looks fine run `sudo chmod -v +r $PL; killall Dock`.

Here is the Italian formatted version of that AppleScript:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell UI element "Finder" of list 1 of process "Dock"
        perform action "AXShowMenu"
        click menu item "Rimuovi dal Dock" of menu 1
    end tell
end tell
```

That’s all, I hope it is useful as a quick complete recap.