# How do I remove the Finder from the Dock automatically at login?

Tags: finder, applescript, dock, login

This is related to [this question here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30415/how-can-i-remove-the-finder-icon-from-my-dock), except that, in addition to removing the Finder, I want to do it automatically. There are several solutions on the web that suggest using this AppleScript:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell UI element "Finder" of list 1 of process "Dock"
        perform action "AXShowMenu"
        click menu item "Remove from Dock" of menu 1
    end tell
end tell
```

Unfortunately, saving this as an application and having it run at login doesn't work; interestingly, running it within `Script Editor` *does* work, but this doesn't solve the problem of removing the Finder automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to create a LaunchAgent (`man launchctl` for more info) that runs the above script via the command-line. Essentially, you want to store the script above in a file, say 'killfinder.scpt' and then run the command `osascript /path/to/killfinder.scpt`.

We want to do this automatically at login, so we use a LaunchAgent. Since I want to use this because I use Pathfinder and my wife doesn't, I'm going to put it in `~/Library/LaunchAgents`, but if you want this to be system wide, put it in `/Library/LaunchAgents`.

You will have three files:

1. **A UNIX script**
2. **An AppleScript** *(optional)*
3. **A LaunchAgent XML plist**

#### Script File

1. Put this in an appropriate path. For example, I stored it in `~/dev/scripts/killfinder.bash`.
2. Create the file and add this content:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   osascript /path/to/AppleScriptFile.scpt
   ```
3. Make sure the permissions are correct (i.e. `chmod ug+x killfinder.bash`)

#### AppleScript File

You can call osascript directly with AppleScript code as an argument. I leave that as an exercise to the reader; in that case, you can creating this file. But if you want to do it this way:
1. Put this in an appropriate path.
2. Create the file and add this content:

```
    tell application "System Events"
        tell UI element "Finder" of list 1 of process "Dock"
            perform action "AXShowMenu"
            click menu item "Remove from Dock" of menu 1
        end tell
    end tell
```

1. Make sure the permissions are correct (i.e. `chmod ugo+r Finder\ Remove.scpt`)

#### LaunchAgent XML plist

1. Put this in `~/Library/LaunchAgents` or `/Library/LaunchAgents` depending if you just want this behavior for your personal account or system-wide.
2. Create a file called `com.<whateveryouwant>.KillFinder.plist` with the following content:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
   <plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
      <key>Label</key>
      <string>com.<whateveryouwant>.KillFinder</string>
      <key>Program</key>
      <string>/path/to/unixscript</string>
      <key>RunAtLoad</key>
      <true/>
   </dict>
   </plist>
   ```

   It's important to make sure the 'string' value after the `Label` key is correct as well as the path to the unix script.

Now all you have to do is exit and login and it should work!