# Restricted files on El Capitan?

Tags: permission, macos, plist

So I wanted to hide the Finder icon on my Dock. 
According to this answer - [How can I remove the Finder icon from my Dock?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30415/how-can-i-remove-the-finder-icon-from-my-dock?newreg=7853552a016a48d2a67c03406a1b7af9) I am suppose to edit DockMenus.plist file. When I tried I had no permission to do that. I tried to use `chmod` (also with `sudo`) on that file with no effect, same message from terminal - `Unable to change file mode on DockMenus.plist: Operation not permitted`. I ran `ls -lOe` on that file and I learned that apparently there is new permission flag called `restricted`.

I still don't know how to get permission to edit that file. Does anyone have any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue only by booting to Recovery Mode (press <kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> during restart) and launching Terminal. This terminal doesn't care abour restricted flag on files. Also found answer here:
[How do I disable System Integrity Protection (SIP) AKA "rootless" on OS X 10.11, El Capitan?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-max-os-x-el)